# Groups overage claim

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I am receiving the group overage claim for a user authenticating against Azure AD. Looks like the below:

`{"src1":{"endpoint":"https://graph.windows.net/TENANTID/users/USERID/getMemberObjects"}}`

My thought was I could then just call that endpoint, which I did like:

```
var authenticationContext =
    new AuthenticationContext(
        ctx.Options.Authority);
var clientCredentials =
    new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

var result =
    await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCredentials);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {result.AccessToken}");

    var httpResponse =
        await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.windows.net/TENANTID/users/USERID/getMemberObjects?api-version=1.6");

    var jsonresult =
        await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I thought this would work, but not it is complaining it wants the method to be a `Post`. Not sure what I would pass in for Content, but it tried it in Postman, and it still failed.

My hope is that I am just making this more difficult than it needs to be, but for the life of me, I cannot find a good definitive example for how to call the Graph API from a MVC Core App.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update**

I changed it to a `Post` and passed in a `null` body, and received an error with code `Authorization_RequestDenied` and value `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`.

Made sure to the give the Application Directory.Read.All permissions.

Comment: Would you like to retrieve group member from graph API?

Comment: I I have tried this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/getMemberObjects` and passed this param in body `{
  "securityEnabledOnly": false
}' which successfully return values.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron ... yes, and would like to just pass the groups overage claim endpoint, e.g. https://graph.windows.net/TENANTID/users/USERID/getMemberObjects

Comment: Try this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenant/users/UserId/getMemberObjects` with this param `{ "securityEnabledOnly": false }' request method  `POST`

Comment: For azure ad Graph your request format is not correct you could try this `https://graph.windows.net/TenantId/users/UserId/getMemberObjects?api-version=1.6`, param `{
  "securityEnabledOnly": false
}` Method Type `POST`, hope it will work

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron thank you so much ... appreciate the help! I tried to just do this now with Postman ... I get an AAD token, using `https://graph.microsoft.com` as the `resource` ... then try to use that token with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/TENANTID/users/USERID/getMemberObjects` with the body you provided ... still get `Authorization_RequestDenied` error.

Comment: Error code 401? If possible update your question with full error message.

Comment: If possible you could accept my answer.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com` and `https://graph.windows.net` are different api

Comment: Yeah they are, `https://graph.microsoft.com` uses Microsoft Graph API and `https://graph.windows.net` uses Azure active directory graph API. I have shown both to trance your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For azure ad Graph your request format is not correct you could try following way

***Rquest URL:***

`https://graph.windows.net/TenantId/users/UserId/getMemberObjects?api-version=1.6`

***Method Type:*** `POST`

***Request Body***

```
{ 
   "securityEnabledOnly": false 
}
```

***Postman Sample:***

[image]

**Permission Required:**

> Permission Type: Application
>
> `Directory.Read.All Or Directory.ReadWrite.All`

See the screen shot:

[image]

For details you could refer this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getmemberobjects-get-group-and-directory-role-memberships-transitive--)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to the bottom of my problem! I needed to change my request to a `POST` and add `{ "securityEnabledOnly": false }` as the body - thanks @MdFaridUddinKiron for your help with this!

The one thing I was missing is granting my application admin consent.

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone else out!